# MongoDB Aggregate then Average

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB query that uses the aggregation framework like this:

```
System._get_collection().aggregate([
        { "$match": {
            "system_id": system.id,
            "utc_timestamp": {
                "$gte": datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0) - datetime.timedelta(days=1),
                "$lt": datetime.datetime.now().replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0)
            }
        }},
        { "$group": {
            "_id": { "$dayOfYear": "$utc_timestamp" },
            "correct": {
                "$sum": { "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$status", 455 ]}, 1, 0
                ]}
            },
            "total_count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }},
        { "$project": {
            "correctness": {
                "$cond": [
                    { "$eq": [ "$correct", 0 ] },
                    0,
                    { "$multiply" : [{"$divide": [ "$correct", "$total_count" ]}, 100] }
                ]
            }
        }}
    ])
```

The output looks like this:

```
{'result': [{'_id': 272, 'correctness': 99.89373007438896}], 'ok': 1.0}
```

I want to add a field to the result which is an average of all the `delay` fields in each matching `System` document.

I tried to add `"delay": { "$avg": "$delay" },` to the `$group` section, but it didn't change the results.

I want a result like this:

```
{'result': [{'_id': 272, 'correctness': 99.89373007438896, 'delay': 5}], 'ok': 1.0}
```

Note the `'delay': 5` above which should be the computed average.

Do I need to add this to the projection somehow? Or, am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any field besides `_id` that you omit from a `$project` isn't included in the output, so you just need to add `delay` to it:

```
{ "$project": {
    "correctness": {
        "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [ "$correct", 0 ] },
            0,
            { "$multiply" : [{"$divide": [ "$correct", "$total_count" ]}, 100] }
        ]
    },
    "delay": 1
}}
```